# Should I use ctest dashboard if I don't use CDash?

Tags: cmake, ctest

I'm redefining my project's cmake configuration based on what I have learned from  Daniel Pfeifer's “Effective CMake" talks, but I still cannot get my head around ctest.

Currently I have the following setup for my tests:

```
enable_testing()
find_program(MEMCHECK_COMMAND valgrind)
# executable
add_executable(myTest ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(myTest ${LIB_LIST})
# test
add_test(NAME myTest_test
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myTest)
add_custom_target(myTest_test
    COMMAND ctest -R myTest_test --output-on-failure
    DEPENDS myTest)
# memcheck
add_test(NAME myTest_memcheck
    COMMAND ${MEMCHECK_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myTest)
add_custom_target(myTest_memcheck
    COMMAND ctest -R myTest_memcheck --output-on-failure
    DEPENDS ${TEST_NAME})
```

and I could run `make myTest_test` and `make myTest_memcheck` and know that I didn't break anything.

It pains me that I have to do this for every test executable (and project is big so I have dozens of them) and even extracted as a function it just feels wrong.

I have read ctest docs (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/ctest/Testing-With-CTest) and dashboards seems almost perfect to me - if I could just run `ctest -R myTest -T test`, `ctest -R myTest -T memcheck` and `ctest -R myTest -T coverage` I would be very happy :) (and even more happy if those commands will trigger build if needed).

The problem is that `include(CTest)` creates targets that I do not need (Continuous/Nightly dashboards with Start/Update/Configure/Submit steps). It will be used solely as experimental builds and executed by devs during coding. For CI I have Jenkins with it's own magic. I would like to end up with:
- Dashboard/Build
- Dashboard/Test
- Dashboard/MemCheck
- Dashboard/Coverage

What should I do? Should I create manually my own dashboard (if it is possible) or drop this idea and stay with my custom targets?